# Magento stock update via models - error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.5 and trying to update stock level of a product programatically using the magento models like this:

```
// Dummy data
$sku = "VCF001";
$qty = 12;

// Check If Product Is Already In Magento
$p_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
if ($p_id)
{
    // Update Stock In Magento
    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p_id);
    $p->setStockData(array(
        'is_in_stock' => ($qty > 0 ? 1 : 0),
        'qty' => $qty
    ));
    $p->save();

    // Success
    echo "Done";
}
else
{
    // Error
    echo "Invalid Sku";
}
```

When this code executes, I get the following error:

## Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 1068

Any idea why this might be?

P.S. `manage stock` option is turned on for this product I am trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it should work:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
if($product) {

    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
    $stock->setData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => ($qty > 0 ? 1 : 0),
    'qty' => $qty
    ));

   $stock->save();

}
```

Keep in mind, this is quite resource intensive, so if you plan to run it on more than a dozen products at a time, you might want something more optimised.

Comment: I get different error now: `PDO::quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 296`